# Responsive Design: Media Queries Vs Window.InnerWidth

Tags: css, responsive-design

I think that for good responsive design we should be relying on Window.InnerWidth which takes in consideration the actual width inside the window, and that it is better than media queries such as - `@media only screen and (max-width: 600px)` which refers only the the window width.

For example: Window.InnerWidth can deal with situations of zooming in and out in the browser.

I assume I am wrong since after all, experts do use media queries, but why is that? 
Why not checking the actual space instead of the window width?

Take a look at this [example](https://codepen.io/Aesthetic_Nerd/pen/gBbqjR) I made, notice how zooming in doesn't change the background color to red

Comment: Zooming in works perfectly for me

Comment: @Gerard notice how in sites like Amazon, or YouTube, they don't get responsive when you zoom in - they don't adjust themselves to phone view.